# Python 2to3 Converted Python Package Does Not Find Script

Tags: python, python-2to3

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.5 installed in Debian Stretch on my 64bit Linux platform.

I have installed PyChem (http://pychem.sourceforge.net/), written in Python2 after converting the python files using the 2to3 script.  There were no warning or error messages during the conversion process.

Installation put the files in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pychem (with pychem-1.0.egg-info in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages).

To test the application I tried:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""
from pychem import pychem
from pychem.pychem import Chem
mol=Chem.MolFromSmiles("CC(oc1ccccC(O)=O)=O"
```

This generated the error message `"No module named 'pychem'"`.

Unfortunately, for me, the problem is beyond the very limited knowledge of computers I possess as an Organic Chemist.  Pointers towards a solution to the problem will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2to3 isn't really intended for end users.  It's a tool that might help developers port their software to Python 3.  If pychem doesn't offer a Python 3 version, you should install it on and use it with Python 2.

Comment: Also, it seems this question might be better asked on superuser or serverfault.  stackoverflow is oriented towards software development questions.